# dpdk vmxnet3 : testpmd failing with "eth_vmxnet3_dev_init(): Device is not configured for our purpose"

Tags: dpdk

I'am trying to use DPDK in FC20 VM, with 2 VMXNET3 interface.

I followed the steps listed in "http://dpdk.org/doc/vmxnet3-usermap". for enabling the VMXNET3 usermode driver

However, the "testpmd" fails/terminates with the below error

```
"EAL: PCI device 0000:03:00.0 on NUMA socket -1

EAL:   probe driver: 15ad:7b0 rte_vmxnet3_pmd

PMD: eth_vmxnet3_dev_init(): Device is not configured for our purpose

EAL: PCI device 0000:0b:00.0 on NUMA socket -1

EAL:   probe driver: 15ad:7b0 rte_vmxnet3_pmd

PMD: eth_vmxnet3_dev_init(): Device is not configured for our purpose

EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
  Cause: No probed ethernet devices - check that CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_IGB_PMD=y and that CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_EM_PMD=y and that CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_IXGBE_PMD=y in your configuration file
"
```

System details :

```
OS : FC 20
Kernel : 3.2.60    
DPDK : dpdk-1.6.0r2    
vmxnet3 : vmxnet3-usermap-1.2
```

Steps done :

```
1. export RTE_SDK=/home/eilp/DPDK/Linux3_2/dpdk-1.6.0r2 
 2. export RTE_TARGET=x86_64-default-linuxapp-gcc
 3. modprobe uio
 4. insmod vmxnet3-usermap.ko enable_shm=2,2 num_rqs=1,1 num_rxds=512 num_txds=512
 5. testpmd -c 0x3e -n 1 -d librte_pmd_vmxnet3.so -- -i --rxq=1 --rxd=512 --txd=512
```

Full error Log:

```
[root@localhost dpdk-1.6.0r2]# ./x86_64-default-linuxapp-gcc/app/testpmd -c 0x3e -n 1 -d librte_pmd_vmxnet3.so -- -i --rxq=1 --rxd=512 --txd=512

    EAL: Detected lcore 0 as core 0 on socket 0
    EAL: Detected lcore 1 as core 1 on socket 0
    EAL: Detected lcore 2 as core 2 on socket 0
    EAL: Detected lcore 3 as core 3 on socket 0
    EAL: Detected lcore 4 as core 4 on socket 0
    EAL: Detected lcore 5 as core 5 on socket 0
    EAL: Skip lcore 6 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 7 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 8 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 9 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 10 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 11 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 12 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 13 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 14 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 15 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 16 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 17 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 18 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 19 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 20 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 21 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 22 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 23 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 24 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 25 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 26 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 27 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 28 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 29 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 30 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 31 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 32 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 33 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 34 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 35 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 36 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 37 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 38 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 39 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 40 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 41 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 42 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 43 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 44 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 45 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 46 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 47 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 48 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 49 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 50 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 51 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 52 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 53 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 54 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 55 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 56 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 57 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 58 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 59 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 60 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 61 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 62 (not detected)
    EAL: Skip lcore 63 (not detected)
    EAL: Setting up memory...
    EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x800000 bytes
    EAL: Virtual area found at 0x7f9890000000 (size = 0x800000)
    EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x200000 bytes
    EAL: Virtual area found at 0x7f988fc00000 (size = 0x200000)
    EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x200000 bytes
    EAL: Virtual area found at 0x7f988f800000 (size = 0x200000)
    EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x7f400000 bytes
    EAL: Virtual area found at 0x7f9810200000 (size = 0x7f400000)
    EAL: Requesting 1024 pages of size 2MB from socket 0
    EAL: TSC frequency is ~2699988 KHz
    EAL: open shared lib librte_pmd_vmxnet3.so
    librte_pmd_vmxnet3 version 1.2
            Copyright 2012-2014 6WIND S.A. provided without warranty.
    EAL: Master core 1 is ready (tid=90d0a880)
    EAL: Core 5 is ready (tid=ddef700)
    EAL: Core 4 is ready (tid=e5f0700)
    EAL: Core 3 is ready (tid=edf1700)
    EAL: Core 2 is ready (tid=f5f2700)
    EAL: PCI device 0000:02:00.0 on NUMA socket -1
    EAL:   probe driver: 8086:100f rte_em_pmd
    EAL:   0000:02:00.0 not managed by UIO driver, skipping
    EAL: PCI device 0000:02:02.0 on NUMA socket -1
    EAL:   probe driver: 8086:100f rte_em_pmd
    EAL:   0000:02:02.0 not managed by UIO driver, skipping
    EAL: PCI device 0000:02:03.0 on NUMA socket -1
    EAL:   probe driver: 8086:100f rte_em_pmd
    EAL:   0000:02:03.0 not managed by UIO driver, skipping
    EAL: PCI device 0000:03:00.0 on NUMA socket -1
    EAL:   probe driver: 15ad:7b0 rte_vmxnet3_pmd
    PMD: eth_vmxnet3_dev_init(): Device is not configured for our purpose
    EAL: PCI device 0000:0b:00.0 on NUMA socket -1
    EAL:   probe driver: 15ad:7b0 rte_vmxnet3_pmd
    PMD: eth_vmxnet3_dev_init(): Device is not configured for our purpose
    EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
      Cause: No probed ethernet devices - check that CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_IGB_PMD=y and that CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_EM_PMD=y and that CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_IXGBE_PMD=y in your configuration file
```

Comment: Could anyone please help me on this trouble

Answer (score 0):

you can change file `config/common_[linux or bsd]`.

Replace `CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_IGB_PMD=n` to `CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_IGB_PMD=y` and recompile dpdk. You must install `libcap` library. I think it...

Comment: @Majid and @xFxJDK this is not the correct answer. `rte_vmxnet3_pmd` requires CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_VMXNET3_PMD to be enabled and not IGB_PMD